# Detecting new USB devices with bash?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, shell-script, usb-storage, dev, watch

I'm writing a bash script that needs to detect when a usb storage device is inserted and assign it to a variable that would otherwise, typically look something like: `usb=/dev/sdb`.

I have a few abstract ideas that involve using `watch`, some kind of `if` / `while` looping construct, and possibly `lsblk -o kname` / `lsblk -o pkname`; but am yet to fully realize anything suitable.

How best could I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can kick off a script using `UDEV`. "udev also handles all user space events raised while hardware devices are added into the system or removed from it" (From http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev)

Inside a file called: `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-usb.rules` add the following:

```
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/path/to/script.sh"
```

Note: You may need to slightly adjust the location of the file depending upon your distribution.
Also Note: You may need to restart before the rule takes effect.